# Passing int and string parameters to thread C++

Tags: c++, c, string, multithreading, parameters

I'm using _beginthead() to start my thread.  I need to pass 3 parameters to the thread: a string and two ints.
Here's what I have, and this by no means is the entire program, and I've taken some things out that have nothing to do with the problem (disregard the mistakes with main, because in my actual program main isn't actually main and it's just a regular function):

```
typedef struct ST
{
    char *ip;
    int port;
    int dur;
}thestruct;  

void main(char **arg_p, int arg_count)
{
    char *ip;
    int port, duration;
    ip = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    ip = arg_p[0];
    port = atoi(arg_p[1]);
    duration = atoi(arg_p[2]);

    thestruct *st;
    st = (thestruct *)malloc(sizeof(thestruct));
    st->dur = duration;
    st->ip = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    st->ip = ip;
    printf("ip: %s\n", st->ip);
    st->port = port;

    _beginthread((void(*)(void*))connect, 0, (void*)st);
}

void connect(thestruct *s)
{
    Sleep(100);
    char *ip = static_cast<char*>(s->ip);
    int port = s->port;
    int dur = s->dur;
    printf("ip: %s\nport: %i\ndur: %i", ip, port, dur);
    _endthread();
}
```

Everything is working great, except the string, ip, isn't getting passed correctly to the thread.  The first printf call prints out the ip perfectly, and then inside the thread, it prints "ip: " and it's blank after that.  Then it goes to a new line and prints out the port and duration perfectly.

I've been researching this problem topic for awhile to no avail because most people only need to pass one string or something like that.  So all I can find from googling is people passing a single string and of course that works.

I pass for example "127.0.0.1 1234 25".  Also, there doesn't seem to be any problem with my struct because like I said, the two integers work perfectly, and I'm not getting any errors on the string, it's just not being passed.

So anyway, if anyone can shine some light on the topic, that'd be great.

Comment: FYI: No need for `typedef struct`/`typedef class` in C++.

Comment: What are you passing as your program arguments?

Comment: My thought is that you're using `char **arg_p` for the first argument when it's supposed to be an integer.

Comment: Spotted two errors in your code:
1st, you can't use `=` to copy C strings (`char *`), you have to use `strcpy`
2nd, Your allocations are buggy. In your case, you're only allocating a single character (your malloc calls args should be `MAX_NB_CHAR+1 * sizeof (char)`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the main problem is that `main()` exits prior to `connect()` having done its printing and flushing what it had printed.

---

Besides this its:

```
int main(int, char **)
```

not the other way round.

---

Another issue is that the thread function is defined to be:

```
void * (*)(void *)
```

So it should be:

```
void * connect(void * pv)  
{
  thestruct * s = pv;
  ...
```

---

Also

```
st->ip = ip;
```

would overwrite the address which just before was returned by the allocation.

You better want to copy the characters:

```
strcpy(st->ip, ip);
```

---

This line

```
ip = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

is redundant as `ip` is overwritten in the next line:

```
ip = arg_p[0];
```

Comment: Disregard problems you see with the main function definition.  Please just keep in mind this is just a code snippet and is leaving out unnecessary code.  Focus more on the structure and the thread, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: An exception occurs in my code when it reaches the newly added line "strcpy(st->ip, ip)".

Comment: You do not allocate enough memory in `st->ip = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));` Its just one byte you give, as `sizeof(char)` is `1`. @user1846111

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that it's your `main` definintion which is causing the problem:

```
void main(char **arg_p, int arg_count)
```

Aside from the fact that `void` is supposed to be `int`, the first argument is supposed to the argument count while the rest are the arguments. Try switching them:

```
void main(int arg_count, char **arg_p)
```